# Disney's common theme of villainesses

Tags: character, disney

Many of Disney Animation Studios movies have had a common theme where the antagonist was a female.  From the Queen of Hearts in Alice in Wonderland, to Cruella DeVille in 101 Dalmations to the Wicked Stepmother in Cinderella to Ursula in The Little Mermaid, the usually male-dominated role of "Bad Guy" has been women.

Does anyone know the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Because most if not all were based on fairy tales with *wicked witches*...or other original stories so you'd have to ask the authors.

Comment: @Paulie_D Disney is still choosing which stories to tell; and seemingly choosing stories involving a female antagonist.

Comment: You have a **very limited** sample over 80 years.... and in the majority of those the protagonist is also female. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Walt_Disney_Animation_Studios_films#Released_films

Comment: Although I'm not sure if the sample provided makes it the rule, but I do think that those tales are after, like Paulie_D said, about young women being pitted against older "nasty" or jealous women and one could probably create a thesis's on either mother & daughter dynamics, generational & culture views on ageism, or perhaps even male patriarchy positioning women against each other/or painting the younger beautiful women as the hero women should aspire to be. It should be noted though that there are films and new books taking a villain's point of view to counteract this.

Comment: By my count it's about 9-10 out of 60ish movies in 80 years....and, again, pretty much all of those were based on external sources (fairy tales and other media) which make them more *suited* to animation than live action (at least pre-CGI).

Comment: I agree that the semantics of trying figure out what Disney kept vs what was changed vs various editions of previous sources vs individual producers on any given work would make this very hard to answer, which is why I used the word "thesis", because that is what this answer would probably look like, but at the same time doesn't mean that certain cultural norms weren't preserved through out time and/or that there isn't evidence that Disney recognizes this and is trying to change those norms.

Comment: There actually is a reason, and it doesn't require a deep thesis, which I'll use as a self-answer if no one knows it.

Comment: I'm not saying that someone somewhere didn't [try] to answer this and shouldn't be considered, but rather I think the answer could probably be contested since these films are based on other sources and/or someone at Disney's reasoning could be seen as subterfuge for what a contemporary audience might see as something else, especially when one looks at Disney's current PC "content in media" behavior. I'm very curious though as what your answer is going to be! :D

Comment: @GendoIkari: Just because the chosen stories contain female villains does not mean that the stories were chosen _because_ they contain female villains.

Comment: @flater Sure, I didn’t mean to imply otherwise. Just that the fact that Disney didn’t write the stories themselves doesn’t really change the nature of the question.

Comment: Based on the answer provided, data suggests that there is not a theme of female Disney villains. There are some, sure, but that doesn't suggest a common theme.

Comment: @sanpaco - As I noted in the answer given, roughly 25% of all Disney villains are female.  What percentage of non-Disney movies contain female villains?  *Maybe* 5%?  So, in terms of ratio, it's actually rather high.

Comment: @JohnnyBones but your question doesn't say anything about Disney compared with non-Disney. If that is what you meant then maybe an edit would be in order because the way it is worded right now seems like you are implying that Disney animation studios has more female than male villains. In any case its ambiguous as evidenced by the many comments from people who misunderstood what exactly you are asking.

Answer (score 11):

## They don't.

Here is a list of "official Disney villains" from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Disney_villains):

- Amos Slade (The Fox and the Hound)
- Big Bad Wolf (Three Little Pigs)
- Captain Hook (Peter Pan)
- Chernabog (Fantasia)
- **Cruella de Vil (One Hundred and One Dalmatians)**
- Doctor Facilier (The Princess and the Frog)
- Edgar Balthazar (The Aristocats)
- Frollo (The Hunchback of Notre Dame)
- Gaston (Beauty and the Beast)
- Hades (Hercules)
- Hopper (A Bug's Life)
- Horned King (The Black Cauldron)
- Jafar (Aladdin)
- **Lady Tremaine (Cinderella)**
- **Madame Medusa (The Rescuers)**
- **Madam Mim (The Sword in the Stone)**
- **Maleficent (Sleeping Beauty)**
- **Mother Gothel (Tangled)**
- Percival C. McLeach (The Rescuers Down Under)
- Pete (Mickey & Co.)
- Prince John & Sheriff of Nottingham (Robin Hood)
- **Queen Grimhilde (Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs)**
- **Queen of Hearts (Alice in Wonderland)**
- Ratcliffe (Pocahontas)
- Ratigan (The Great Mouse Detective)
- Scar (The Lion King)
- Shan Yu (Mulan)
- Shere Khan & Kaa (The Jungle Book)
- Sid Phillips (Toy Story)
- Stromboli (Pinocchio)
- Sykes (Oliver & Company)
- **Ursula (The Little Mermaid)**
- **Yzma (The Emperor's New Groove)**

10 females out of 35.

## Edit:

Here is a more complete list I made in chronological order based on [this website's list](http://disneyvillains.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Disney_Villains) (villains added by me are in italic):

- **Queen Grimhilde (Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs)**
- Stromboli, *Honest John and Gideon* (Pinocchio)
- Chernabog (Fantasia)
- **Lady Tremaine (Cinderella)**
- **Queen of Hearts (Alice in Wonderland)**
- Captain Hook (Peter Pan)
- **Maleficent (Sleeping Beauty)**
- **Cruella de Vil (One Hundred and One Dalmatians)**
- **Madam Mim (The Sword in the Stone)**
- Shere Khan & Kaa (The Jungle Book)
- Edgar Balthazar (The Aristocats)
- **Madame Medusa** & *Mr. Snoops* (The Rescuers)
- Amos Slade (The Fox and the Hound)
- Horned King (The Black Cauldron)
- Ratigan (The Great Mouse Detective)
- Sykes (Oliver & Company)
- **Ursula (The Little Mermaid)**
- Percival C. McLeach (The Rescuers Down Under)
- Gaston & *LeFou* (Beauty and the Beast)
- Jafar & *Iago* (Aladdin)
- Scar (The Lion King)
- Ratcliffe (Pocahontas)
- Frollo (The Hunchback of Notre Dame)
- Hades (Hercules)
- Shan Yu (Mulan)
- *Clayton (Tarzan)*
- *Kron (Dinosaur)*
- **Yzma (The Emperor's New Groove)**
- *Rourke & **Helga Sinclair** (Atlantis: The Lost Empire)*
- *Gantu (Lilo & Stitch)*
- *Scroop (Treasure Planet)*
- *Alameda Slim (Home on the Range)*
- ***Doris (Meet the Robinsons)***
- *Agent (Bolt)*
- Doctor Facilier (The Princess and the Frog)
- **Mother Gothel (Tangled)**
- *Turbo (Wreck-It Ralph)*
- *Hans (Frozen)*
- ***Bellwether (Zootopia)***

13 females out of 50.

Note that I only listed "main antagonists".

Comment: But do they pay their villainesses as much as their villains?

Comment: It would be interesting to see these in chronological order...

Comment: ...and also a list of Disney protagonists?

Comment: @Kwola-T I agree. I'll work on the list when I have the time today.

Comment: Full list is much longer - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Walt_Disney_Animation_Studios_films#Released_films

Comment: @Paulie_D Yup, just updated it.

Comment: Of course your list excludes movies without villains

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes. Some characters are actually hard to classify. Should Yokai from Big Hero 6 be listed? The hunter in Bambi? The dogcatcher in Lady and the Tramp? Regardless, the initial claim of the question is clearly false.

Comment: In the grand scheme of movies with female antagonists, you still have to admit they occur more frequently in Disney Animation Studios movies than in any other studio.  That's 26% for Disney!  Outside of Disney, maybe 5% at best?

Comment: @JohnnyBones Possibly. Maybe write another question in that sense then? ;-) It will probably be too broad though, unless maybe if you restrict it to animation studios.